# Is there a way to get the number of additional commits in git without awk?

Tags: git

If I've got some tags in git I can use this:

```
git describe --tags | awk -F- '{ print $2 }'
```

To display the number of commits since my last tag. Is there a way to get this number just using git commands?

Comment: That command doesn't show the number of commits since my last tag - what's the expected output? Should it be `print $3`? Note: my last tag has a dash in it as well, perhaps why this is different to your result

Comment: The short answer is "no", because `git describe`'s internal counting algorithm is quite complex. If you know some specific tag, though, you can get reasonably close, maybe close enough, with `git rev-list --count <tag>..` (i.e., count revisions reachable from `HEAD` but not from the given `<tag>`). This will give misleading values in the presence of merges; `--first-parent` can help, but might also hurt. (Hence the complexity of the counting inside `git describe`.)

Comment: Mostly I was hoping for some feature akin to what you can get with git log where you can provide some format specifiers.

Comment: @torek - you **can** get the latest tag programmatically

Comment: @RobbieAverill - yes, dash in tagname is the issue, fortmat of [git describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) is obviius `TAGNAME-COUNT_AFTER-gHASH`

Comment: @LazyBadger: ah, I see, sneaky: get `git describe` to produce it for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git dark-voodoo:

```
git rev-list --count `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` HEAD
```

or maybe slightly changed into (haven't Git, can't test, writing from memory)

```
git rev-list --count `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`..HEAD
```

Note:

```
git log <RANGE> --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

will work also, but **a lot** slower, than rev-list

Comment: And here again I'll think about Mercurial "made by Man for the people". Just compare git's spaghetti with shot and clean `hg log -l 1 -T"{latesttagdistance}\n"`

Comment: It's the middle one of these: count revisions after the tag, up to HEAD, with `<tag>..HEAD` where `<tag>` is from your `git describe` trick.